# Trigger Checkbox using HREF different Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to auto check a checkbox from an href from a different page?

Example
I have a link in the front page

```
<a href="/page2">Toys</a>
```

Page2

```
<input type=checkbox name="toys" />
```

if I click the link TOY in the front page, it will go to the next page and preselect Toy checkbox or have the Toy selected automatically

My page 2 contains a loop based on checkbox so I wanted to trigger the checkbox outside of the page and execute the loop

Page2

```
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET"):  
    
  $categories = get_categories();
 foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="<?= $cat->term_id ?>" class="postfilter_checkbox"/><span class="filter_txt"><?= $cat->name ?></span></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With document.referrer you can check how the user navigated to the page and if the user comes from your page you can activate the checkbox.

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
if(referrer == 'https://yourDomain.com/PageWhereTheUserShouldComeFrom.html'){
    document.getElementById("checkToys").checked = true;
}
```

Comment: what if the referrer is a header menu link ?

Comment: I think it should work even if the link on you front page is a header menu link. You can try it and if it doesn't work you can output var referrer for example with
<p id="info"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = referrer;
</script>

Comment: one more question how would i trigger  the checkbox if I used document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = referrer;

Comment: I was thinking doing var x = document.getElementById("covid").innerHTML = referrer; 
if (x) {
  jQuery('input[value="15"]').prop("checked", true);
}

Comment: you wont trigger the checkbox with document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = referrer; you will trigger it with document.getElementById("checkToys").checked = true; 
You can just use document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = referrer; if it wont work, to see which link is in you variable referrer and what you have to set in if(referrer == 'hereShouldBeTheContentOfReferrer'){

Comment: thanks I am kinda new to script so basically, it would look like that?
<script>
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = referrer
if ( document.getElementById("info").innerHTML) {
  document.getElementById("checkToys").checked = true; 
}
</script>

Comment: no it would look like my answer, copy the code in my first answer an set it in <script> tags, then just change "https://yourDomain.com/PageWhereTheUserShouldComeFrom.html" to the link of your front page and everything should work